# new Firebase () function deprecated?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Writing a demo multiplayer game where db's are dynamically created and removed on disconnect by either player. Attempting to use the new database () function, but does not appear to create the DB's on the fly. Wondering if the function is now deprecated and there is another way to create the DB's on load.

```
var config = {
// Firebase API Stuff
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);
var database = firebase.database();
$(document).on('ready', function() {
var database = new Firebase("https://myFireBaseDBSite.firebaseio.com/");
var Player1 = new Firebase('https://myFireBaseDBSite.firebaseio.com/player1');
var Player2 = new Firebase('https://myFireBaseDBSite.firebaseio.com/player2');
var PlayerChat = new Firebase('https://myFireBaseDBSite.firebaseio.com/chat');
```

Comment: I'm wondering if it's because I need blaze to support multiple DB's? Not sure..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `new Firebase(...)` syntax was used in Firebase SDK 1.x and 2.x. Since the introduction of the 3.x SDKs in May 2016, a different syntax has been used.

While there is a [migration guide from 2. to 3.x](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-web), at this point I'd recommend simply starting from the [latest documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup).

The equivalent references can be gotten with:

```
var database = firebase.database();
var root = database.ref();
var Player1 = database.ref('player1'); // or root.child('player1');
var Player2 = database.ref('player2');
var PlayerChat = database.ref('chat');
```